# Read List of Elements using apache commons

Tags: java, xml, spring, apache-commons

I am using spring and apache configuration library.

Is there any way to get the list under authentication tag as an java object?

```
<authentication>
 <entry>
   <key> name  </key>
   <value> Rishabh </value>
 </entry>
  <entry>
   <key> Id  </key>
   <value> 2515247 </value>
 </entry>
  <entry>
   <key>  pass </key>
   <value>password </value>
 </entry>
</authentication>
```

My authentication POJO looks like this.

```
protected List<Authentication.Entry> entry;
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Unclear problem. That xml fragment can be parsed into a java object using jaxb for example. What apache commons has to do with this?